# Set id using model in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJs and wanted to ask either it is possible in Angularjs to set id of an input field using model : $scope.modelName.
In Jquery It can be done like:-

```
    $('.projShortName').attr('id', somevar);
```

Thank You

Comment: So basically I have to set everything using json data. Even values and Id's. Previously I was using jquery to do everything. But I have to set from the controller. I know how to set value but i am confused about id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can provice id dynamically. In controller place following code:

```
$scope.somevar = "ABC";
```

And in Html place this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="abc" id="{{somevar}}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. Basically you are the person who exactly answered my question according to my scenario. It worked. Thanks again @Jenny

Comment: But I really don't understand why someone gave negative vote to my question. This is really bad. This platform is developed to ask questions

Comment: Do not think about down votes. That is individual's choice. And happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the prettiest of solutions, but you can try this:

```
<input ... class="projShortName" id="{{ modelId }}" ng-model="modelName">
```

You can then set and use these in your controller:

```
$scope.modelName = 'some value';
$scope.modelId = 'input-id';
```

Comment: Hi, I have to set id from controller. I have to set everything on the basis of json data. is it possible to set id like value: $scope.modelName = val;

Comment: Yes. I changed my answer to take your scope variable name into account. When you assign a value to $scope.modelName, or change it, the id attribute of the input will change.

Comment: Hi, the scenario is that I have two variables var val and var id. Now I am setting value as $scope.modelName = val; var id have different value.

Comment: Then you can change `modelName` in my example to another name, for example `modelId`.

And then set $scope.modelId to id or whatever value you want.

Comment: Yes basically this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a very basic thing and one of the first things you should have learned when going through Angular tutorials.

```
<input id="{{somevar}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can set model value as element's id and access that model value from controller.

```
$scope.idVal = "XYZ";
```

`<input type="text" ng-model="abc" id="{{idVal}}"/>`